# Git temprorary revert commit and put back

Tags: git, github

I am facing this issue a lot now because of the uncertainty of business and so many 3rd party API we are using, so please read and understand my issue and provide a working answer because it will be set as standard and will be used a lot.

assume you have a text file test.txt on git repo.
the very first commit is

```
a
```

> git add and git commit with message "a is added" with commit id
> `ebfdacf`

2nd commit

```
a
b
```

> git add and git commit with message "b is added" with commit id
> `21ea0c1`

3rd commit

```
a
b
c
```

> git add and git commit with message "c is added" with commit id
> `c93c85a`

4th commit

```
a
b
c
d
```

> git add and git commit with message "d is added" with commit id
> `v32f17m`

but code `c` was dependent on some 3rd party API which was not developed yet, so now I need to temporary revert develop branch up to working code `b` only, and once the 3rd party API is available then again add code `c` and `d` into it.

I tried so many ways available on google, but none of them is working for me. so right now we are doing everything manually, manually removing code from the branch then once 3rd party API is available then manually adding code in the repo which is very error-prone.

please suggest some solution.

Comment: You could go through one or two solutions you considered and why they don't work for you. For example, have you tried the standard github or gitlab flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 - rewriting history**

First move `HEAD` to `develop` so we can work on it:
`git checkout develop`

Now move `develop` back to `b`:

`git reset --hard 21ea0c1`

(You might want to put a temporary branch on `d` so the commits don't disappear from the graph / get garbage collected. It can be done with `git branch some_temporary_name v32f17m`)

At this point we're waiting for the 3rd party API to become available. While we wait, there's nothing stopping you from committing new stuff to `develop` if you wish. You can keep working on `develop` as usual.

When the 3rd party API is finally available, do:

```
# Restore commit c
git cherry-pick c93c85a

# Restore commit d
git cherry-pick v32f17m
```

If you have many commits that you want to restore, you can use a range instead of cherry-picking them one by one:

```
git cherry-pick c93c85a^..v32f17m
```

(Note that without the `^` the first commit in the range is excluded)

**Option 2 - reverting and then cherry picking**

We can cancel commits c and d by doing:

```
# Cancel commit d
git revert v32f17m

# Cancel commit c
git revert c93c85a
```

This will create two new commits that are the "opposite" of d and c - thus essentially "cancelling" them out.

When we want to restore them, once the new 3rd party API becomes available, we can cherry-pick them. See **Option 1** for how to do that.

**Option 3 - Start a new branch**

We can create a new branch, let's call it `temporary_develop`, that will be used as the new develop until that 3rd-party API becomes available

Create the new branch at commit b:

```
git checkout -b temporary_develop 21ea0c1
```

Use this branch until the 3rd-party API becomes available.

When you finally have the 3rd-party API -

- If you made changes inside `temporary_develop` that you now want in `develop` - merge them back into develop:

```
git checkout develop
git merge temporary_develop

# Optionally, you can now delete temporary develop
git branch -d temporary_develop
```

- if you haven't made changes inside temporary develop, then you can simply delete it and go back to using develop:

```
git checkout develop
git branch -d temporary_develop
```

Comment: Hi Omer, thanks for your reply, I am running your answer against my test repo in a bit bucket. so far I have reached.

now revert code back to 3, so 
git reset --hard 21ea0c1 // command you mentions git reset develop --hard 21ea0c1 is giving error.

ok, so now as per code, it back to code b but now git status is showing no changes. how to push the commit now.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, fixed

Comment: ok, but still once I am running `git reset --hard 21ea0c1` yes as per code I can see its back to `b` but if I do git status, it's not showing any changes in my test.txt file, so how to push it now?

Comment: Git status doesn't display those changes because they are already committed. It's not changes you need to commit. "Reset" simply moves the branch back in the commit graph to where you tell it. There's nothing that needs to be "committed". You can now `git push --force` the branch.  Note that I suggest Option 2 much more than Option 1 - it doesn't include rewriting history or force pushing - which cause a lot of issue / confusion when working with other people